# Выделение памяти на двойной указатель для матрицы в CUDA

Tags: c, распараллеливание, cuda, nvidia

Для того , чтобы распараллелить умножения матрицы я создал три матрицы:

```
int** a=NULL;//выделил памяти,заполнил случайными значениями
int** b=NULL;//выделил памяти,заполнил случайными значениями
int** c=NULL;//выделил памяти,заполнил элементы нулями
```

Создал матрицы,которые будут в GPU

```
int** aGPU=NULL;
int** bGPU=NULL;
int** cGPU = NULL;
size_t pitch;
```

И пытаюсь записать в них значения, которые были в матрицах `а` и `с` соответственно, чтобы распараллелить вычисления в кернеле.

Выделяю на них память:

```
cudaMallocPitch((void**)&aGPU, &pitch, N, N);
cudaMallocPitch((void**)&bGPU, &pitch, N, N);
cudaMallocPitch((void**)&cGPU, &pitch, N, N);

cudaMemcpy2D(aGPU, N*sizeof(int), a, N * sizeof(int),N * sizeof(int), N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);   
cudaMemcpy2D(bGPU, N*sizeof(int), b, N * sizeof(int), N * sizeof(int), N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy2D(cGPU, N*sizeof(int), c, N * sizeof(int), N * sizeof(int), N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Меня интересуют несколько вещей:

1. Что такое `pitch`, зачем он нужен и как с ним управляться?
2. Правильно ли я пытаюсь выделить память `cudaMalloc`?
3. Как скопировать данные из матрицы `а` в матрицу `аGPU`?

Минимальный самодостаточный пример в студии:

```
int **a = NULL;
    MakeMem(&a);
    initValue(a);
    //show(a);
    int** b = NULL;
    MakeMem(&b);
    initValue(b);
    int** c = NULL;
    MakeMem(&c);
    int** aGPU=NULL;
    int** bGPU=NULL;
    int** cGPU = NULL;
    size_t pitch;


    cudaMallocPitch((void**)&aGPU, &pitch, N * sizeof(int), N);
    cudaMallocPitch((void**)&bGPU, &pitch, N * sizeof(int), N);
    cudaMallocPitch((void**)&cGPU, &pitch, N * sizeof(int), N);

    cudaMemcpy2D(aGPU, pitch, a, N * sizeof(int), N * sizeof(int), N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy2D(bGPU, pitch, b, N * sizeof(int), N * sizeof(int), N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);// вот тут происходит ошибка копирования
    cudaMemcpy2D(cGPU, pitch, c, N * sizeof(int), N * sizeof(int), N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Что такое pitch, зачем он нужен и как с ним управляться?

**pitch** (*шаг*) — это размер одной строки двумерного массива в байтах. Дело в том, что ради ускорения доступа к памяти при обработки матриц построчно, начала строк выравниваются на определённые значения (типовое — 512 байт, но может отличаться в зависимости от устройства). т.е. адрес элемента матрицы `[Row][Column]` будет вычисляться по формуле:

```
T* pElement = (T*)((char*)BaseAddress + Row * pitch) + Column;
```

> Правильно ли я пытаюсь выделить память cudaMalloc?

Скорей всего нет, забыл умножить указать размер типа, ширина ряда указывается в байтах:

```
cudaMallocPitch((void**)&aGPU, &pitch, N*sizeof(int), N);
```

> Как скопировать данные из матрицы а в матрицу аGPU?

Здесь почти правильно, только для второго аргумента нужно указывать `pitch` в качестве размера ряда:

```
cudaMemcpy2D(aGPU, pitch, a, N * sizeof(int), N * sizeof(int), N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

---

**Документация:** [CudaMallocPitch()](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g32bd7a39135594788a542ae72217775c), [cudaMemcpy2D()](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g3a58270f6775efe56c65ac47843e7cee)

Comment: ,всё равно исключение по памяти при СudaMemcpy2D

Comment: @Elvin, [mcve] в студию...

Comment: ,добавил в вопрос подробности

Comment: @Elvin, Во-первых, нужно больше самодостаточности (желательно до уровня скопировал-собрал-воспроизвёл)... а во-вторых у тебя почти наперняка *массив указателей*, а не *двумерный массив* (смотря что `MakeMem` делает)